# Gimp does not allow me to select any format other than A0 for new image

Tags: gimp

I am want to create a new image in Gimp in A4 size. When I click on template, I can’t choose A4 or any other format except A0.

[image]

Before, it allowed me to choose any format.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify what you mean by “I can’t choose A4”? For example, does it not show in the drop-down menu, or does it show, but clicking it has no effect?

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the problem. For me the template dropdown has A4 available. I don't know why you don't have that option available. Perhaps you might want to consider re-installing the lastest version just to make sure, or if you feel so inclined, you can have a look at the *templaterc* file stored in the program directory. You can add templates in there by editing the file in a text editor.

However it doesn't matter really, since you can just create your own custom size anyway.

To manually create an A4 canvas, type a height of 297mm, and a width of 210mm. Note in the screenshot below there has been some rounding of the sizes due to the fact that one pixel is the smallest unit in a raster image, but it's only a few hundredths of a millimetre and therefore insignificant.

For example

[image]

Comment: The templates are user-configurable and stored in a user-specific templaterc, as such the state survives re-installs. Adding, removing and editing them is usually done via the Templates dialog, see https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-template-dialog.html - and there's an issue report about the inability to update or restore the user-specific templates: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/1347

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Hmm . . but then you could just delete the *templaterc* file after uninstalling, and before reinstalling. I managed to locate a couple on my own computer, one in %APPDATA% and another one in the program folder under GIMP 2\etc\gimp\2.0.  Looks like the directories can become a bit of a mess if you don't delete old left over folders after an uninstall.

Comment: You're not supposed to delete anything there yourself, that's the point.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Yes, but if you want a totally clean reinstall, then it might be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. but for me, not even re-install a newer version solved my problem. I also checked in the templaterc (C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\etc\gimp\2.0) file, and it looked normal. delete it and re-installed again but nothing!

The only thing I could really do was manually create the format I needed and save it as a new template. going to File -> save as a new template.

I write this if this helps anyone.

Comment: You probably need to do a clean re-install. That is remove any left over folders or files after uninstalling. These can cause problems if you reinstall over the top of them.